# Mathematical interpretation of pressure (gradient)

Tags: physics, mathematical-modeling

I'm having some problem with the following.

Usually, the pressure of some mass on an area A is defined by $$P=\frac{F}{A}$$ where $F$ is the force of the mass exerted due to gravity. However, here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force#Continuum_mechanics

we find the identity $$-\nabla P =\frac{F}{V}$$ where $V$ is some volume (and probably an area is also allowed here). However, I was trying to see this identity with the Gradient theorem but failed. So essentially my question is: where does the gradient come from?

Comment: Just looking at units, $\nabla P$ divides the units of P by a unit of distance.  In terms of units, $V$ = unit of distance * units of area.  So I don't think an area would be allowed for $V$ as the units wouldn't match.

Comment: So it's really simply $V=A h$ for any height $h$ in any of the directions. This yields, dividing by "h" a directional derivative. Repeating this for alle the directions the yields the gradient?

Comment: Pressure is force divided by area, not mass.

Comment: can't you say the pressure of some mass?